# app not launching on iPhone (iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, ios5

Just installed and app on my iPod touch using a developer provisioning profile. The app works fine some time but after some time it fails to start on iPod (iOS 5) touch, just tries to launch but in half way through closes .... even the splash is also not visible.

I checked the crash log from device says something like this.

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/DBC8A071-F305-4095-8FF5-76DDC99DDDEE/ApplicationName.app/ApplicationName
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 199.5

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x72fff +ApplicationName armv7  <1f10c6b4168c3503908fead68d17ddb5> /var/mobile/Applications/DBC8A071-F305-4095-8FF5-76DDC99DDDEE/ApplicationName.app/ApplicationName
0x2fe79000 - 0x2fe9afff  dyld armv7   /usr/lib/dyld

From log it seems like its failing to load the **SenTestingKit** library but how it works for some time????
And if I remove this framework what should be the alternative for iOS 5.

Please shed some light on this rather strange issue.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are some problems with loading libraries in iOS 5, so just try to clean the project in xCode 4 and build it again. That maybe help you, because after a cleaning all paths will be set up for new.

Answer (score 7):

You should only be linking to SenTesting in your Testing target.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
Try to delete the derived Data, then clean the project and restart Xcode. If its still not working, check the Target dependencies of your library.

**Second:** Try to mark the SenTestingKit as "optional".

[image]