# App crashes after power down on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios7, xcode5, cocoapods

I am running iOS7 on an iPhone 4S and my app runs fine until I power down my iPhone and power it back on.  When I launch my app it simply just flashes a black screen and then takes the user back to the iPhone app icon view.  Also, my app uses RestKit .20.3 and ZBar for bar code scanning and is built using Xcode 5 on Mountain Lion.  Then I connect my iPhone back to Xcode and then rerun the app and everything is fine again. Has anyone else experienced this issue.  Below is a snippet from my crash log;

```
Date/Time:           2013-10-03 22:23:41.334 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/DC06399E-15F3-46B1-B194-24CC93B763E2/    Genie.app/Genie
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 324

Binary Images:
0x2be76000 - 0x2be96fff dyld armv7  <b37cba000c7d3f8ea414f060d45ce144> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30e47000 - 0x30f4cfff CFNetwork armv7  <0ad158ad8b7a3716ad04ffde6081754c>      /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30fbf000 - 0x311affff CoreData armv7  <9338ccb7c0f2377196e181eb10b15ef5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x312f3000 - 0x31416fff CoreGraphics armv7  <17a70d032a013c06b9a4d244b100e2b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31b99000 - 0x31d83fff Foundation armv7  <75c827267c5a3c85a3b21a9459d3c312> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x329f5000 - 0x32a58fff MobileCoreServices armv7  <5d5b5ca6dd7a305688d5a4d47363d534> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3380f000 - 0x3384ffff Security armv7  <492fcd48d4de3f29b01799ace718d3d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
```

Comment: Are you running any unit tests on your app?  It seems to be crashing because of the SenTestingKit test framework, but not sure why it's running then.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but, after researching this more, I believe this has more to do with the version of Zbar I am using in my project.

Comment: SenTestingKit is highlighted in RED under my Pods Frameworks folder in Xcode 5.  Why is it RED?

Comment: That normally just means that it gets compiled during the build.  It would fail during building if there were something seriously wrong like the pod wasn't linked in correctly.  This is a runtime error and it looks like you have setup an exception breakpoint to catch it

Comment: Was able to solve my issue by making SenTestingKit "optional" under the linked libraries in my Target, Build Phases.  Also, used some of the tips in this posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895296/app-not-launching-on-iphone-ios-5 but, due to your original comment I was able to piece this together.  Thanks again for your useful comments.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve my issue by making SenTestingKit "optional" under the linked libraries in my Target, Build Phases. Also, used some of the tips in this posting stackoverflow.com/questions/7895296/… but, due to your original comment I was able to piece this together. Thanks again for your useful comments.

Comment: Why is your app linking against SenTestingKit? Only your test target should.

Comment: I tried both linking SenTestingKit to my test target and even removed it from my project altogether and got my original issue described above.  When i put SenTestingKit back in as "optional" in my link lib list for my main app, the issue went away.  Any other ideas or suggestions on the resolution are welcome.

Comment: If it was truly removed, it doesn't make sense that anything would try to load it. Your workaround avoids the problem but doesn't fix it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for tracing or tracking down what would be referencing SenTestingKit in my code?

Comment: I assume you've done a "Find in Project" for "sente". Are you using any static libraries?

Comment: Turns out that Sentestingkit is being used by the pods I have imported into my workspace for RestKit.  I'll have to research this more to see why that is and if anything further can be done other than making "SenTestingKit" optional in my link libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Test support pods like

- Specta
- OCMock
- OCHamcrest
- Expecta

don't belong in your main target (assuming you don't use OCHamcrest matchers for non-test purposes). They need to be targeted exclusively to your test target, something like this:

```
target :MyTests, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Specta', '0.1.8'
    …etc…
end
```

Comment: This what i have in my Podfile;inhibit_all_warnings!

    def import_pods
  pod 'Specta', '0.1.8'
  pod 'OCMock', '2.1.1'
  pod 'OCHamcrest', '2.0.0'
  pod 'Expecta', '0.2.1'
  pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.21.0'
  pod 'JSONKit', '~> 1.4'
  pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.0.0'
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end

platform :ios, '7.0'
import_pods

Comment: With that info, I've completely rewritten my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I had to circle back on this.  This is what i updated my pod file to...  Do I need to update my pods again for this to take effect?  inhibit_all_warnings!

def import_pods
  pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.21.0'
  pod 'JSONKit', '~> 1.4'
  pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.0.0'
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end

  target :MyTests, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Specta', '0.1.8'
    pod 'OCMock', '2.1.1'
    pod 'OCHamcrest', '2.0.0'
    pod 'Expecta', '0.2.1'
    end

    platform :ios, '7.0'
    import_pods

Comment: Yes, do a `pod install`